# Cannot create comments from Post view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Post` that `has_many :comments`. The form that will post the comment will be shown along with the post in `posts/show.html.erb`. I have a `comments_controller` that should handle the creation of comments. Searching on google, I found

```
<%= form_for([@post, Comment.new], :controller => 'comments', :action => 'create') do |f| %>
```

But this doesn't work. How do I do this ?

Comment: We can't help you if you just say, "It doesn't work."  What do you want to happen?  And what happens instead?

Comment: I want to be able to create a `comment` thats associated with the post ie do `@post.comments.build`. I'm getting error `action 'update' not found in PostsController`.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you have in the post and comments controller as well as the code that you have in your posts/show.html.erb file? or if you would like take a look at this implementation https://github.com/mlpinit/mlpinit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
#...

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
#...
```

Then in the form

```
form_for @post do |f|
  f.fields_for :comments do |c|
    c.text_field :title
    #...
  f.submit
```

this would create the associated object through active record's accepts_nested_attributes_for, which doesn't require a separate comments_controller.  you are submitting to the posts controller, which is handling creating the associated object during the update of the post.

with a comments_controller, you could do one of two things:

send item_id as a param to comments_controller#new, grab the item, then build the new comment from it

```
@post = Post.find(params[:item_id); @comment = @post.comments.build
```

put the post_id in a hidden field on the form and just create the comment as normal

```
# in the controller
@comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])

# in the view
form_for @comment do |f|
  f.text_field :title
  #...
  f.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id
```